# ConnectIB : Please log in to IB TWS or IB Gateway?

Tags: r

I'm using R Studio and trying to use getIBEquities(c('SPY', 'DIA'))
and get the error message: Error in ConnectIB(c(125:129, 150))

so I have tried to use ConnectIB() with 
con1 <- ConnectIB(c(125:129, 150)

but get the next message
Error in ConnectIB(c(125:129, 150)) :
 Please log in to IB TWS or IB Gateway

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to TWS to use its API; and of course you need to enable the API:

[image]